# Mule jaxb xml to object transformer- target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Tags: jaxb, mule, mule-studio

I am doing a xml to object conversion in mule using jaxb but, whenever i am using xml tag i am getting this error- 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException - The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

following is my input message-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://test.standalone.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:getResultString>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <inputXml>
                  <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
         <autoBean>
            <autoID>1</autoID>
            <country>sdf</country>
            <model>sdf</model>
            <year>sf</year>
        </autoBean>
         ]]>
         </inputXml>
      </test:getResultString>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

if i remove "" transformation is working fine, but it is mendatory for me to use the .

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by removing the white space between wsdl element and cdata as follows,
compare it with the above request message in question

```
 <inputXml><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<autoBean>
    <autoID>4</autoID>
    <country>sdf</country>
    <model>sdf</model>
    <year>2013-01-01</year>
</autoBean>
         ]]>
```